# Schrodinger equation to find general wave function

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I am trying to answer this question:
[image]

I have tried solving the Schrodinger equation using separation of variables.

However in the later time wave function i can not seem to get the exp(-3i...)

My current workings are:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding

\begin{align*}
  \Psi(x,0) &=
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \sin \frac{\pi x}{a}+
   \frac{2}{\sqrt{a}} \sin \frac{\pi x}{a} \cos \frac{\pi x}{a} \\
   &=
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \sin \frac{\pi x}{a}+
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \sin \frac{2\pi x}{a} \\
  \omega_{n} &= \frac{n^2 \pi^2 \hbar}{2ma^2} \\
  \psi_{n} (x,t) &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{a}} e^{-\omega_{n} t} \sin \frac{n\pi x}{a} \\
  \Psi(x,t) &=
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \exp \left( -\frac{n^2 \pi^2 \hbar}{2ma^2} \right)
   \sin \left( \frac{\pi x}{a} \right)+
   \frac{1}{\sqrt{a}} \exp \left( -\frac{4n^2 \pi^2 \hbar}{2ma^2} \right)
   \sin \left( \frac{2\pi x}{a} \right) \\
   &= \frac{\psi_{1}(x,t)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{\psi_{2}(x,t)}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{align*}

Comment: where does the exponential term come from in the psi n (x,t)

Comment: Note that $$i\hbar \psi_{t}=-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \psi_{xx}$$
$\psi_{n}(x,t)$ is an eigen state.

Comment: and why does the second exponential term in the solution have a 4/2

Comment: Don't forget the factor $e^{-i\omega t}$ outside.  $$e^{-i\omega t}(1+2e^{-3i\omega t} \ldots)=?$$

Comment: I'm sorry but i really don't understand, why that happens and why the fact psi n is an eigen state means you then get psi n (x,t) has the exponential term in it

Comment: What's your background?

Comment: currently studying quantum mechanics and fluid dynamics as part of third year maths degree

Comment: Try reading [THIS](http://www.reed.edu/physics/courses/P342.S10/Physics342/page1/files/Lecture.6.pdf), for mixed states please read **6.2.2** page 8 onwards.